# How to scrape a table by manipulating Javascript in inspector? Page only reveals current day's data but I want to go back in time and scrape

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

**What I would like to do:**

http://www.nea.gov.sg/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution-control/psi/pollutant-concentrations/type/pm25-1hr/time/0100#pollutant

I'm referring to the 2nd and 3rd table on this page. Unfortunately, it only reveals the data for the 'day' you are viewing the page. I'd like to be able to go back to Sept 1 and scrape this data into a Google Sheet. I only need the 1-hr PM2.5 concentration levels from the second table & 3-hr PSI readings from the third table - but if I can get the whole lot, the better.

**The problem**

I can't see any way to access the data unless I was somehow able to manipulate the date of access. It is a government agency and I imagine they are running this off a massive spreadsheet BUT chances are scraping this data might be near impossible.

**The code**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var typebaseUrl = '/anti-pollution-radiation-protection/air-pollution-control/psi/pollutant-concentrations/time/0100';

    function changetype(ddl) {
        var strTime = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

        if (strTime != null) {
            var npage = typebaseUrl + "/type/" + strTime + "#pollutant";
            window.location = npage;
        }
    }
</script>
<h1 id="pollutant">
    1-hr PM<sub>2.5</sub> (µg/m<sup>3</sup>)<sup>b</sup> Readings on 28 Oct 2015
</h1>
<p>
    View reading for:
    <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderTitle$C005$DDLType" id="ContentPlaceHolderTitle_C005_DDLType" class="default" onchange="changetype(this);">
 <option value="SulphurDioxide">24-hr Sulphur Dioxide</option>
 <option value="PM10">24-hr PM10</option>
 <option value="PM25">24-hr PM2.5</option>
 <option value="Ozone">8-hr Ozone</option>
 <option value="CarbonMonoxide">8-hr Carbon Monoxide</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="PM25-1Hr">1-hr PM2.5</option>
 <option value="NitrogenDioxide">1-hr Nitrogen Dioxide</option>

</select>
</p>
<div>
    
        
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" class="noalter">
            <tr class="even">
                <td width="16%" align="center">
                    <strong>Time</strong>
                </td>

                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>1am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>2am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>3am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>4am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>5am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>6am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>7am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>8am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>9am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>10am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>11am</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>12pm</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>North</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    87
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    52
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    49
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    70
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    61
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    62
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    16
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    5
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    7
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    8
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    12
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    17
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>South</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    66
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    63
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    53
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    63
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    72
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    51
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    5
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    3
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    6
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    23
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    30
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    27
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>East</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    55
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    68
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    70
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    47
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    60
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    37
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    4
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    5
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    7
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    8
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    18
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    28
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>West</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    49
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    40
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    48
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    58
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    51
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    46
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    12
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    4
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    2
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    10
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    9
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    24
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>Central</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    52
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    64
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    47
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    44
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    54
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    42
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    9
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    6
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    2
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    9
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    18
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    18
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr class="even">
                <td width="16%" align="center">
                    <strong>Time</strong>
                </td>

                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>1pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>2pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>3pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>4pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>5pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>6pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>7pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>8pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>9pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>10pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>11pm</strong>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center"><strong>12am</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>North</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <strong style="font-size:14px;">33</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>South</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <strong style="font-size:14px;">35</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>East</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <strong style="font-size:14px;">55</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>West</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <strong style="font-size:14px;">32</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <strong>Central</strong>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <strong style="font-size:14px;">33</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    -
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to be able to go back to Sept 1 and scrape this data into a Google Sheet.

There are some ways for you to get "*back into the future"/past* to get info.

1. Ask site owners (gov. agency) for publisihing outdated data. API access might be enabled.
2. Scrape daily and save data into a DB and after a while you'll accumulate past data for your needs.

   > manipulate JavaScript in inspector

You don't need to "manipulate JS in [browser] inspector* to fast scrape. [Scraper](https://webscraping.pro/scraper-google-chrome-extension-review/), the Google Chrome plugin does excellent to fast scrape browser info into a Google Sheet.

Comment: Thanks Igor. Unfortunately, this particular government agency doesn't provide this data historically as an API or a CSV - I'd even be happy with a PDF but to no avail.

My only other option right is now to scrape a Twitter feed @sghazealert to get data backdated from October 1. Looks like that might have to be it! Thanks.